# Haskell irrefutable pattern matching

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

In order to get a head start into the path of Haskell, I chose the book by one of its creators Hudak. So, I am going through the gentle introduction to Haskell.

I got stuck at trying to understand the following statement:

> Technically speaking, formal parameters are also patterns but they never fail to match a value.

From my little but relatively greater habituation with languages like C (or let's broadly say as non-functional languages), I could form that formal parameters are the arguments in the definition of a function. So, suppose there were a function like the following in C:

```
int func_add(int a, int d)
```

then passing a value of some other type like string will be a failure in pattern matching if I am correct. So calling `func_add` as `func_add("trs", 5)` is a case of pattern mismatch.

With a heavy possibility of an incorrect understanding or interpretation this similar situation can occur very well in Haskell as well when a piece of code calls a function by passing arguments of different types.

So, why is it said that in Haskell formal parameters are irrefutable pattern matching?

Comment: In some sense, you can boil it down to "variables are irrefutable, literals are refutable, and combinations are refutable if any part is refutable". For types with only one constructor (like a tuple), a seemingly refutable pattern like `(x, y)` (or, as it can be rewritten, `(,) x y`, a refutable literal followed by two irrefutable variables) can be considered irrefutable because after type checking, *only* values created by `(,)` are legal.

Comment: Ergo, a formal parameter is irrefutable because it is a variable.

Answer (score 10):

What you describe is **not a pattern**, it is a **type**. Haskell has types as well, and these are resolved at *compile* time. Each type can have several patterns. For example a list is defined as:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue | Other String
```

Now we can define a function `foo`:

```
foo :: Color -> String
foo Red = "Red"
foo Green = "Green"
foo Blue = "Blue"
foo (Other s) = s
```

The elements in boldface are all *patterns*. But these are not irrefutable: the first one will check if we have given the function a `Red`, the second whether we have given it `Green`, the third if the value is `Blue`, and finally we have a pattern `(Other s)` that will match with all `Other` patterns (regardless what the value of `s` is), since `s` is a *variable*, and a variable is an irrefutable pattern: we do not perform any checks on the value of the string.

Mind that these checks are done at *runtime*: if we would however call `foo "Red"`, we will get a type error at *compile time* since the Haskell compiler knows that `foo` has type `Color -> String`.

If we would have written:

```
foo :: Color -> String
foo c = "Some color"
foo Red = "Red"
```

`c` is an irrefutable pattern: it will match any `Color` object, so the second line `foo Red` will never match, so `c` is an *irrefutable pattern*.

Comment: @Wilhem : So in a nutshell , type checking is done at compile time . As such  calls to "foo" will be validated when  a value from  the listed ones in the data constructor is passed .

Comment: @Wilhem : And pattern matching is used to evaluate the outcomes of a function in this case . But I think I didn't understand the part about formal parameters being irrefutable . Could you please tell me a little more on that ?

Comment: Well a variable like `c` is irrefutable since it matches *all possible* kinds of input (that satisfy the type constraint).

Comment: @Wilhelm : Ok . Can I conclude that  "c" is the formal parameter here ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: yes.

Comment: @Wilhem : Thanks a  lot

Answer (score 7):

No, passing a value of some other type is not a failure in the pattern matching. It's a type error, and the code won't even compile. Formal parameters are irrefutable patterns *for a well-typed program*, which is the only kind of program that the compiler allows you to run.

Comment: That would be a compilation error only in case of functional languges (or well typed or strictly typed languages) ..right ?

Comment: I guess in "c" , the compiler does not check this.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, you can define types in various ways. One of these is to introduce a *sum type*, like this:

```
data FooBar = Foo Int | Bar Bool
```

You could attempt to write a function like this, using pattern matching:

```
myFunction (Foo x) = x
```

That would, however, be a partially matched function, and if you try to call it with `myFunction (Bar False)`, you'd get an exception.

You can, on the other hand, also define single-case sum types, like this:

```
data MyInt = MyInt Int
```

Here, you can write a function like this:

```
myFunction' (MyInt x) = x
```

Here, you're still using pattern matching, but since there's only a single case, this is a complete match. If the calling code compiles, the match can't fail.

The above `MyInt` is really only a wrapper around `Int`, so you could say that if you write a function that takes an `Int`, like this, it's the same sort of pattern matching:

```
myFunction'' :: Int -> Int
myFunction'' x = x + 42
```

While `Int` doesn't have a value constructor that you can use to pattern-match on, `x` is a pattern that always matches an `Int` value. Therefore you can say that a function argument is a match that always succeeds.

Comment: Seeman : Tthanks a lot , but I think I need to understand a little bit more about type constructors and data constructors before being able to completely understand your answer.